# Make "continue" button appear when items selected and disappear when items unselected

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

My question is abou make "continue" button appear when items selected and disappear when items unselected using JavaScript.

```js
var typpro = document.getElementsByClassName("typpro"),
    continubutton = document.getElementsByClassName("continue");
var w;
for (w = 0; w < typpro.length; w++) {
    typpro[w].onclick = function () {
        'use strict';
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        if (this.classList.contains("active")) {
            continubutton[0].style.height = "100px";
        } else {
            continubutton[0].style.height = "0px";
        }
    };
}
```

```html
<div class=" col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="typpro">
        <button>Volume Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class=" col-xs-12">
    <div class="typpro">
        <button style="width:98%">Other</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class=" col-xs-12">
    <div class="inputpro">
        <input type="text" placeholder="your Problem">
    </div>
</div>
<div class=" col-xs-12">
    <div class="continue">
        <button>Continue</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Krolos Ck! Welcome to SO - in order for us to help you out better, and for it to benefit you, we ask that you post the code that you already have, and explain anything you've already done in trying to solve your problem! We're here to answer questions and give suggestions, not do code for you. Cheers!

Comment: <div class=" col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                            <div class="typpro">
                                <button>Screnen</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class=" col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                            <div class="typpro">
                                <button>Battery</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

Comment: var w;
for (w = 0; w < typpro.length; w++){
    typpro[w].onclick = function () {
        'use strict';        
        this.classList.toggle("active");
       
            if(this.classList.contains("active")){
                continubutton[0].style.height = "100px";
            } else {
                continubutton[0].style.height = "0px";
            }
    };
}

Comment: this is the code

Comment: For future, I'd recommend editing your question and adding the code there. There is an entire markdown structure that makes it easier for us to help you out. Here is a link to that for your reference! https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: iam added the code

Comment: The code doesn't contain selectable controls.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the solution is

```
    for (let btn of typpro) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let token = 0;
    this.classList.toggle('active');
    for (let i = 0; i < typpro.length; i += 1) {
      if (typpro[i].classList.contains('active')) {
        token += 1;
      }
    }
    if (token > 0) {
      continubutton[0].style.height = '100px';
    } else {
      continubutton[0].style.height = '0';
    }

  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you've got a couple of things working against you with your code as it stands.

Firstly, you need to actually define your `continubutton` variable, like so:

HTML

`<button id="continubutton" style="display: none;">Continue</button>`

JS:

`var continubutton = document.getElementById('continubutton');`

Then, you also need to define your `typpro` variable, like so:

JS:

`var typpro = document.getElementsByClassName('typpro');`

For what you're trying to do, I went with `display: inline` and `display: none`, instead of the height change because there would be a fair amount of additional CSS you would need to do to accomplish this. But here is the final result:

HTML:

```
<div class=" col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <div class="typpro">
            <button>Screnen</button>
        </div> 
    </div> 
    <div class=" col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"> 
        <div class="typpro"> 
            <button>Battery</button>
        </div> 
    </div> 
    <button id="continubutton" style="display: none;">Continue</button>
    </div>
```

And the JS:

```
var w;
    var typpro = document.getElementsByClassName('typpro');
    var continubutton = document.getElementById('continubutton');
    for (w = 0; w < typpro.length; w++){
        typpro[w].onclick = function () {
            'use strict';
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            if(this.classList.contains("active")){
                continubutton[0].style.display = "inline"; 
            } else {
                continubutton[0].style.display = "none"; 
            } 
        }; 
    }
```

**EDIT:** Since using `height` seems to be the route we need to go, here is updated code:

```js
  var w;
  var typpro = document.getElementsByClassName('typpro');
  var continubutton = document.getElementsByClassName('continue');
  for (w = 0; w < typpro.length; w++){
   typpro[w].onclick = function () {
    'use strict';
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    if(this.classList.contains("active")){
     continubutton[0].style.height = "100px"; 
    } else {
     continubutton[0].style.height = "0px"; 
    } 
   }; 
  }
```

```html
<div class=" col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
   <div class="typpro">
    <button>Screnen</button>
   </div> 
  </div> 
  <div class=" col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"> 
   <div class="typpro"> 
    <button>Battery</button>
   </div> 
  </div> 
  <div class="continue" style="height: 0;overflow:hidden;">
   <button id="continubutton">Continue</button>
  </div>
  </div>
```

It's important that you set the initial height on your `<div class="continue"></div>` container, and that you set it to `overflow: hidden;` so anything that falls outside of the bounding box is hidden from view. This will allow you to animate the height so the button appears "hidden" until an option is selected.

Comment: Updated my answer to include a solution that uses height.

Comment: your code work when select more than one button but when unselect only one the button continue disapper even other buttons active

Comment: are you understand me